# Create disposable software container

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, virtualization

I'm about to start a project where I have to test a number of software solutions on a RPi2 running Raspbian without X.

It would be too much effort to reinstall raspbian on the SD card or to cleanse the SD card after each test.
I want to create a container, in which I install software and process some data, test it and then dispose the container, without impacting the host.

Is it possible to use `chroot`, `lxc` or `docker` in this case? If so where do I start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker on Raspbian?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15389/docker-on-raspbian)

Comment: I suggest systemd-nspawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is a great option but it might be a bit heavy. I don't have much experience with lxc but chroot may also work.

Other options such as Snapcraft or Flatpak could work too. Snapcraft is really easy to get up and running - http://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/your-first-snap