# What's the optimal way to install latest Docker on Raspbian? legacy docker-engine package from official get Docker

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, docker

When installing official Docker packages [I get a warning](https://github.com/rancher/install-docker/blob/master/17.03.1.sh#L135-L143):

```
curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh                                                                                        
Executing docker install script, commit: 29533f9                                                                               


  WARNING: raspbian is no longer updated @ https://get.docker.com/                                                             
           Installing the legacy docker-engine package...                                                                      


+ sudo -E sh -c sleep 3; apt-get update                                                                                        
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease [14.9 kB]                                                            
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease                                                                            
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages        
(..)
+ sudo -E sh -c sleep 3; apt-get update; apt-get install -y -q docker-engine                                                   
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease            
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages                                                                  
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Get:1 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie InRelease [48.7 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                        
Get:2 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main armhf Packages [3,540 B]                                                                                                                                                                              
Get:3 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:4 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en [454 B]                                                
Get:5 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:6 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                                
Get:7 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:8 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                                
Get:9 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                             
Get:10 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                               
Get:11 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                            
Ign https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                                                                                                                       
Get:12 https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en [454 B]                                                                                                                                                                               
Ign https://apt.dockerproject.org raspbian-jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                                          
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB                                                                                                                                                                                               
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                  
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB                                                                 
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en                                                                    
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                        

Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg       
  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
Fetched 52.2 kB in 2min 0s (434 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount git git-man libapparmor1 liberror-perl libltdl7 rsync
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-arch git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount docker-engine git git-man libapparmor1 liberror-perl libltdl7 rsync
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 104 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libltdl7 aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount libapparmor1 liberror-perl git-man git rsync
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org
PING mirrordirector.raspbian.org (93.93.128.193) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=48.3 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=51.1 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=47.8 ms
^C
--- mirrordirector.raspbian.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 47.851/48.911/51.111/1.295 ms
```

What other ways to install latest Docker engine? What's recommended?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:
Uninstall old versions
Older versions of Docker were called docker or docker-engine. If these are installed, uninstall them:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

It’s OK if apt-get reports that none of these packages are installed.

The contents of /var/lib/docker/, including images, containers, volumes, and networks, are preserved. The Docker CE package is now called docker-ce.

Extra steps for Wheezy 7.7
You need at least version 3.10 of the Linux kernel. Debian Wheezy ships with version 3.2, so you may need to update the kernel. To check your kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
```

Enable the backports repository. See the Debian documentation.

## Install Docker CE:

See this post: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/#extra-steps-for-wheezy-77

Answer (score 0):

The recommanded way is to follow Docker installation document. It works on my Raspberry Pi 2 (I have 2 of them one with Raspbian the other Ubuntu).

See my detailed answer here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75226/26910